# Merge two sequences with a pointer in C - "Violation Call"

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, access-violation

I have a 2D array and I have to merge all his columns which are progressive. I've already split the array into `swap[]` but I got "Violation call" when I try to put the `swap[]` in the sorted sequence. I'm using pointer and I think that is where the problem is. Can anyone help?

```
void MergeSequence(float seq[], float newSeq[], int *seqIndex, int newSeqIndex)
{
    int j = *seqIndex;

    for(int i=0; i<newSeqIndex; i++)
    {
        seq[*seqIndex] = newSeq[i];
        *seqIndex++;
    }
}
```

`seq[]` is the row which is going to be displayed, `newSeq[]` is the row i'm trying to add in `seq[]`. The pointer has to be the current position of the big `seq[]` and the last parameter is for the length of the the row which I'm adding.
Hope this is not very confusing :D

Comment: I suspect you're accessing your array out of bounds.  You should add print statements to track the values of your variables, and then go from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*seqIndex++;` probably does not do what you think. It should be `(*seqIndex)++;` instead to increment the value pointed to by `seqIndex`. The code you have currently increments the pointer itself, and also performs a dereference operation and discards its result.

You also need to make sure that `seq` points to an array with at least `*seqIndex + newSeqIndex` entries, and that `newSeq` points to an array with at least `newSeqIndex` entries.